# Python/Selenium not switching pages for Chrome 78 when executing Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script that switches site pages that contains tables. It have worked fine for months (last time with Chrome version 76), but after the installation of new Chrome version 78.0.3904.70 an error has been set:

```
        driver.execute_script("__doPostBack('action','Page${}')".format(page))

      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
        'args': converted_args})['value']

      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)

      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

    JavascriptException: javascript error: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
      (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)
```

I've used the command `driver.execute_script("__doPostBack('action','Page${}')".format(page))` to switch the pages. I've searched and tryed by solutions using "value" but nothing worked.

I searched for chuncks of the messages `'args': converted_args})['value']` and

```
JavascriptException: javascript error: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)
```

but none was helpful.

My Python version is 3.6 and Chromedriver version 78.0.3904.70. Windows 10 x64

Comment: It sounds like 78 uses strict mode for javascript. I wonder if there's a flag for that. Anyway I don't think things like that were ever supposed to work - you should be clicking on the element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, something like this might work:

```
el = driver.execute_script("""
  return document.querySelector('[onclick*="Page${}"]')
"""
el.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I looked for more information because your answer was returning 'None'. What worked was href*="Page$2". Now the next step will be to change the page index (2, 3, 4, ...). To change the index, I'm thinking to use el.value or querySelectorAll and find the page index I need. Can you give any clue what is the best way?

Comment: PS: for a quick solution to move on, I've used a for loop with page indexes and if statements to select the page, but it is working for a few cases (only 5 ifs) but I can have more than twelve pages to switch

Comment: Sounds about right. please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: What it is the solution worked for you please ,thanks